# Flow Direction not working with the ios when using converters

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Using xamarin forms V 3.0.0.482510

I change the Flow Direction of the Xaml page using converter, That happens when Current.Culture.IsRightToLeft changes.

In Android it works Fine and changes the direction, But in IOS the Direction is always Left To Right.

XamlPage:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="MEGA.Views.StartNow" 
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" 
             BackgroundColor="#941a24" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MEGA.Converters"
             FlowDirection="{Binding RTL,Converter={StaticResource BoolToString}}" >
    <!-- RTL is a boolean property contains the IsRightToLeft value -->
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:BooleanToString x:Key="BoolToString" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Margin="30,0,30,50">

            <Label Text="This Is a Test Text"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And here is the Convert method

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if ((bool)value == true)
        return "RightToLeft";
    else
        return "LeftToRight";
}
```

I have a doubt that the Converter or static resource fails somehow in the ios project because when I set

```
FlowDirection=RightToLeft
```

flow direction manually the direction changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `FlowDirection` is not a string you need to modify your converter to :

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if ((bool)value == true)
        return FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
    else
        return FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
}
```

Then your binding and converter will work on iOS.

Answer (score 2):

FlowDirection direction is an enum. Return the enum you want instead of the string. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.flowdirection?view=xamarin-forms and here https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/FlowDirection.cs